# PHP prepare statement insert query

Tags: php, mysql

There is an error in the following code.

**demo.php:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td> Enter Name </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="txtname"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Enter Email </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="txtemail" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Add" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <?php
      if(isset($_REQUEST['message']))
      {
      echo $_REQUEST['message'];
      }
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<?php
include 'db_operations.php';
  if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']) and isset($_POST['btnsubmit']) == "Add")
  {
    extract($_POST);
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO author(name,email) VALUES (?,?)";
    $param_type = "ss";
    $param = $txtname.','.$txtemail;
    $result = $db->executeQuery('insert',$insertQuery,$param_type,$param);
    header("Location:demo.php?message=$result");  
  }
?>
```

**db_operations.php:**

```
<?php
  function executeQuery($query_type,$query_string,$param_type,$param)
  {
      $result = "Error";

      set_error_handler("logError");

      if(!$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query_string))
      {
          trigger_error("Failed to prepare statement for " . $query_type ." query");
      }

      if(!$stmt->bind_param($param_type,$param))
      {
          trigger_error("Failed to bind parameter for " . $query_type ." query");
      }
      if(!$stmt->execute())
      {
          trigger_error("Failed to execute " . $query_type ." query");
      }
      else
      {
          $result = "Record ".$query_type."ed successfully";
      }

      $this->stmt->close();
      $this->con->close();
      return $result;
  }
?>
```

There are 2 php files. The first script accepts a record and makes an insert query, and the second script execute that query.

However, when I execute the program, it shows me the following error:

> *Error Type : E_WARNING
>   *Error String : mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
>   *Error Line : 55
>   *Error File : F:\wamp\www\food_app\inc\admin_db_operations.php
>   *Error Date : 09-02-2018 06:43:09 pm
>
> *Error Type : E_USER_NOTICE
>   *Error String : Failed to bind parameter for insert query
>   *Error Line : 57
>   *Error File : F:\wamp\www\food_app\inc\admin_db_operations.php
>   *Error Date : 09-02-2018 06:43:09 pm
>
> *Error Type : E_USER_NOTICE
>   *Error String : Failed to execute insert query
>   *Error Line : 61
>   *Error File : F:\wamp\www\food_app\inc\admin_db_operations.php
>   *Error Date : 09-02-2018 06:43:09 pm

Please guide me on how I can improve my function to work correctly.

Comment: Consider that you have two placeholders (i.e. `?`) and one parameter: `$param = $txtname.','.$txtemail;`... `2 != 1`...

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the error message:

> Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

You're specifying a different number of variables than you're supplying.  Let's take a look at where you bind the values:

```
$stmt->bind_param($param_type,$param)
```

You're passing the string `"ss"`, indicating that there are two parameters to bind.  But then you're passing only a single value in `$param`.  That value is a single string composed of the two different values you want.

You have to bind the values separately, not as a single string.

The `bind_param()` function expects a variable number of arguments.  So you should be able to pass through that same concept in your function.  It's been a while, but I *think* it might look something like this:

```
function executeQuery($query_type, $query_string, $param_type, ...$params)
```

That `...` would tell PHP that `$params` is a [variable-length argument list](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).  Then I think you can just pass that list along to `bind_param()`:

```
$stmt->bind_param($param_type, $params)
```

And when you call your function, instead of concatenating your values into a single string, pass them as separate values:

```
$db->executeQuery('insert', $insertQuery, $param_type, $txtname, $txtemail)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code:

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO author(name,email) VALUES (?,?)";
$param_type = "ss";
$param = $txtname.','.$txtemail;
```

This line is wrong:

```
$param = $txtname.','.$txtemail;
```

Why? because you are converting 2 variables in just 1. Then when you try to bind the parameters you get the error mentioned on your description because the query is expecting 2 parameters not 1. If your idea is to pass this parameters "all-in-one" you can create an array:

```
//$param = $txtname.','.$txtemail; // this line is wrong
$param = array($txtname, $txtemail); // This line is correct!
```

Then you change the way you "bind" the values on your code, changing this code:

```
if(!$stmt->bind_param($param_type,$param))
      {
          trigger_error("Failed to bind parameter for " . $query_type ." query");
      }
```

for this one:

```
if(!$stmt->bind_param($param_type,$param['0'],$param['1']))
      {
          trigger_error("Failed to bind parameter for " . $query_type ." query");
      }
```

More information of binding parameters here: [mysqli stmt bind](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and the ways you can use an array here: [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, none of your PHP code will run because your condition includes this :

```
isset($_POST['btnsubmit']) == "Add"
```

while you surely meant

```
$_POST['btnsubmit'] == "Add"
```

Because the result of `isset()` is gonna be either `true` or `false` but surely not `"Add"`

Second your `$param` variable should be an array like this :

```
$param = [$txtname, $txtemail];
```

Because now, you only passed one parameter consisting of a string that has a comma in the middle but still only one string so that would go fill the first `?` in your query and `MySQL` is waiting for a second parameter. That's what the `WARNING` says